# Using typeahead.js with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular2-forms, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to use typeahead.js with Angular 2 (to make use of the Bloodhound feature, as it's the best one out there). However I am running into difficulty importing the js file into the project.

I have the following in the index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the typeahead files:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.1.1/bloodhound.min.js"></script>
```

I also have the jQuery imported as follows in the the systemjs.config:

```
..
map: {
      'jquery': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js',
}..
```

And I have the jQuery in the ngAfterViewInit method:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

            console.log("jQuery is ready");

            // constructs the suggestion engine
            var states = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
                local: states
            });

            $('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1
            },
                {
                    name: 'states',
                    source: states
            });




    }
```

The jQuery works (confirmed by the console log entry). However I get the following error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).typeahead is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

and

> ERROR TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

Comment: Try without the $(document).ready and directly in ngAfterViewInit instead? (which will trigger after document is ready, so it makes no sense to add to the document.ready event)

Comment: I've removed the document.ready event however I'm still getting the same error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

Comment: This plunk does not get the error - and it has your code in ngAfterViewInit: https://plnkr.co/edit/Xvm0zwut4on8n6LNJVHL?p=preview Also see in index.html - did you add your typeahead script tag before the angular scripts?

Comment: I've changed the typeahead to be before the angular scripts and still getting the same error ('typeahead': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js') - I do have 2 jQuery scripts being imported though - through the index.html and the system.config, which could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, try removing jquery from system.config. In the plunk I showed you it's only in index.html as a script tag.

Comment: Still the same :( - the jQuery was added into the system.config as I couldn't find a way to use the javascript in different components. Adding the script in the index doesn't seem to work globally :( thanks for the help so far

Comment: Got it working! Removed the jQuery from the system.config and declared the jQuery in the modules file with declare var jQuery: any with the script in the index.html. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the my solution. Hope someone can help this.

Install typehead.js type definition using following command.

```
npm install --save @types/typeahead
```

Add following files to angular-cli.json file too.

```
"assets/js/bloodhound.min.js",
"assets/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"
```

Do following in OnInit() method of the component

```
 const suggestions = [{
          value: 'string1'
        }, {
          value: 'string2'
        }, {
          value: 'string3'
        }, {
          value: 'string4'
        }, {
          value: 'string5'
        }];

 let bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        sufficient: 3,
        local: this.suggestions
 });

 $('#tagsInput .typeahead').typeahead({
      hint: true,
      highlight: true,
      minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'suggestions',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: bloodhoundSuggestions
  });
```

I have installed jQuery too.

Please make sure to add following to app.component.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

And Make sure to import following on your component file.

```
declare const Bloodhound;
declare const $;
```

Component Html File

```
<div id="tagsInput">
   <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```